# LocalFileSystem is not defined PhoneGap

Tags: extjs, cordova, touch, filereader

I know that the question has been asked before but I can't find any workaround...

I am trying to get a file thanks to PhoneGap File feature, so I took the example on their documentation website, and get the above error.

This is my code :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
            }

            function gotFS(fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.root.getFile("toto.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
            }

            function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
            }

            function gotFile(file){
                    readDataUrl(file);
                    readAsText(file);
            }

            function readDataUrl(file) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                            console.log("Read as data URL");
                            console.log(evt.target.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

            function readAsText(file) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                            console.log("Read as text");
                            console.log(evt.target.result);
                    };
                    Ext.Msg.alert('toto',reader.readAsText(file), Ext.emptyFn);
            }

            function fail(error) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('error',error.code, Ext.emptyFn);
            }
```

Here is my config.xml file :

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    </feature>
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
<icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
```

I tried installing the cordova file plugin with the phonegap CLI, which actually succeeded... but any change appearing on my app.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot!!

ps: I'm using Sencha Touch 2.3.1 with Sencha Cmd to build my app but it probably doesn't change anything since other features like batterystatus or physical button binding work fine...

Answer (score 0):

include following in your Config.xml

```
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
  <feature name="File">
     <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
  </feature>
  <feature name="FileTransfer">
     <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
  </feature>
  <feature name="Storage">
     <param value="org.apache.cordova.Storage" name="android-package"/>
  </feature>
```